# Special name for middle window rail

Tags: windows

I'm confused by window terminology. Does that middle flat ledge where two window sashes meet that also has the window latch have a special name? In our house it always winds up collecting house plants, holiday decorations, ect. Lately we are getting ants coming in on left side where the sashes slide. I was calling it a sill, but that apparently is the bottom flat area.

Comment: Can you take a photo and mark the piece of concern, your description is quite confusing unless you are talking about the sash track at the bottom, but it is not where a latch is usually located.

Comment: @r13 pretty simple - it's "where the top of the bottom sash meets the bottom of the top sash and the sash locks are installed". Unfortunately, that's a real mouthful and needs a shorter name. Great question for which I have no answer...

Comment: @FreeMan Didn't realize it is a vertical window from reading the description. Can you provide the "mouthful" long name to satisfy the inevitable curiosity of many?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the horizontal rail where the windows meet is the "check rail". There are two of them, and they are the lower sash check rail and upper sash check rail.  Just search ["window check rail"](https://www.google.com/search?q=window+check+rail&tbm=isch) for images of it.

[image][[image]][image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwZKN.png)

Comment: Your tag is great, it shows the window parts, but I think you mean “meeting rail”.

Comment: @LeeSam, there's a good chance it has multiple names that have changed over time or in different regions.  One or the other is a good jumping off point to research windows more and find out what might be wrong.

Comment: Meeting rail is how I learned it in Eastern Canada carpenter school.

Comment: I thought a "meeting rail" was that brass thing down at the local pub.. :D